# Can I see my UI on my camera but not on my map?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

My trouble is that I want to do a fighting game and create my UI for the health bars.

However, I just wanted to associate my UI with all the maps (I do not know if it is possible)

Moreover, when I apply my UI in a scene, my UI is visible on the map but I only want the 2 cameras of the players to render it.

Can someone help me?

[image: Camera Picture]
[image: Map Picture]

Comment: I don't really understand the issue .. but you can put objects on [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and let your camera only render specific layers via the `Culling Mask` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the HP (or other UI elements) visible on every map, you can use a `GameObject` that is set to `DontDestroyOnLoad()` (just remember to control how you add it, so it won't appear in the main menu). To display it only in fights, not on the map overview, you can use layers, as derHugo said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613616/can-i-see-my-ui-on-my-camera-but-not-on-my-map#comment133400656_75613616)  .